# Query does not return end date records

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, ruby-on-rails-5

I have a date range search in rails but for somereason the query below does not include dates that are same as end date.

`Sale.where("created_at >= ? AND created_at <= ?","Fri, 15 Jul 2016", "Sat, 16 Jul 2016")`

anyone care to enlighten me?

I am using date_fields in a form to send date and search within Sales table.

Answer (score 1):

What is the database that you are using? I think that depending on the database provider it cannot determine the > operator.

For date ranges the best would be to use this statement that translates into "sales"."created_at" BETWEEN ? AND ?

Something like this:

```
Sale.where(created_at: Date.today - 1.day..Date.today)
```

Modify to use the date range to suit your use case

hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

It seems the reason it did not bring up my records on end date is because i needed to clarify the time as well. So i needed to search records by end of day.

I am using postgres database and here is what worked.

```
Sale.where("sales.created_at >= ? AND sales.created_at <= ?", date_start.beginning_of_day, date_end.end_of_day)
```

Comment: You could also try: Sale.where("sales.created_at between ? and ?", date_start.beginning_of_day, date_end.end_of_day)